# Canonical Distribution (Partition Function)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

For the canonical distribution
$$
w_{n}=e^{(F-E_{n})/T},
$$

is the sum
$$
Z=\sum_{n}e^{E_{n}/T}
$$

a sum over energies or a sum over states? Perhaps this is a silly question, but Landau and Lifshitz call this a "sum over states." But what if $E_{n}$ is degenerate? Is an individual term in the sum a contribution of all the degenerate states sharing that energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a sum over states.

The partition function can also be written as
\begin{align}
  Z = \sum_\alpha g_\alpha e^{-\epsilon_\alpha/kT}
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is an index which labels levels, $\epsilon_\alpha$ is the energy of level $\alpha$, and $g_\alpha$ is the degeneracy of level $\alpha$.  This follows from the sum over states by noting that in that sum, terms that all have the same energy combine into one term with a factor equal to the number of times that term appears (which is just the degeneracy).

You will probably find the following physics.SE post and answer as it provides more detail and an example:

[How do you determine the value of the degeneracy factor in the partition function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79022/how-do-you-determine-the-value-of-the-degeneracy-factor-in-the-partition-functio/79026#79026)

Comment: So, does the version I gave in the question statement implicitly assume that there is no degeneracy ($g_{\alpha}=1$)?

Comment: Actually the point is that the two expressions (sum over states and sum over levels) are the same and completely general.  You can sum over states without degeneracy factors, or you can sum over levels with degeneracy factors.  Both forms give precisely the same number and work for arbitrary systems with discrete energy spectrum.

Comment: Oh I get it now. $n$ is not necessarily a single quantum number, but the set of quantum numbers that label a distinct state.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly right.

Comment: @user201175 I edited the answer and included a link at the end which might also be helpful.